# htaccess hide subdirectory with RewriteBase

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

From 
http://www.example.com/eblasts/_ire

To
http://www.example.com/eblasts

I have this, but doesn't work...

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/eblasts/_ire
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ eblasts/$1 [L]
```

What did I mess up on?

Answer (score 0):

your rewriterule rewrite `http://www.example.com/eblasts/_ire` to
 `http://www.example.com/eblasts/eblasts/_ire`

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/eblasts/_ire
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ eblasts [L]
```

Update:

```
RewriteRule ^home.html$ _ire/home.html
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Aseman, I have a question for you. I don't think it is working properly. I really want http://www.mysite.com/eblasts/_ire/home.html to appear http://www.mysite.com/eblasts/home.html